# Iterate on multiple list in single for loop in Jinja

Tags: loops, for-loop, ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I have the following ansible template:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/local/bin/haproxy-ea-health-check \
  -reference-servers="{% for validator_ip in trusted_validators_ips|difference([ansible_default_ipv4.address]) %}http://{{ validator_ip }}:9100{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}" \
  -reference-servers="{% for validator in groups[network+'_reference']|difference([inventory_hostname]) %}http://{{ hostvars[validator]['hostname'] }}.{{ hostvars[validator]['domainname'] }}:9100{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}" \
```

Which renders nicely like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/local/bin/haproxy-ea-health-check \
  -reference-servers="http://192.168.1.200:9100,http://192.168.1.201:9100,http://192.168.1.202:9100,http://192.168.1.203:9100" \
  -reference-servers="http://server1.domain.com:9100,http://server2.domain.com:9100,http://server3.domain.com:9100" \
```

Now, I was trying to actually loop the 2 lists (trusted_validators_ips and groups[network+'_reference']) in the same line, while keeping also both ansible "difference" filters so I wouldn't have any conflict printing the IP/DNS name of the machine itself.

I have tried something like this, but the syntax doesn't seem to be good:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/local/bin/haproxy-ea-health-check \
  -reference-servers=""{% for validator_ip,validator in trusted_validators_ips|difference([ansible_default_ipv4.address]),groups[network+'_reference']|difference([inventory_hostname]) %}http://{{ validator_ip }}:9100,http://{{ hostvars[validator]['hostname'] }}.{{ hostvars[validator]['domainname'] }}:8899{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}"http://{{ validator_ip }}:9100{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}" \
```

It returns:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

My desired output would be all those IPs and DNS names above appended in one single line.

Is this kind of loop even possible in an ansible template? If not, would you guys have any suggestions on how I could perform such thing?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really make it work using for loop with 2 lists, but I made it work differently, if come in handy one day for anyone:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/local/bin/haproxy-ea-health-check \

      -reference-servers="{% for validator_ips in trusted_validators_ips|difference([ansible_default_ipv4.address]) %}http://{{ validator_ips }}:8899,{% endfor %}{% for validator_hostname in groups[network+'_reference']|difference([inventory_hostname]) %}http://{{ hostvars[validator_hostname]['hostname'] }}.{{ hostvars[validator_hostname]['domainname'] }}:8899{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}" \
```

And we have it rendering nicely:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/local/bin/haproxy-ea-health-check \

  -reference-servers="http://192.168.1.200:9100,http://192.168.1.201:9100,http://192.168.1.202:9100,http://192.168.1.203:9100,http://192.168.1.204:9100,http://server1.domain.com:9100,http://server2.domain:9100,http://server3.domain.com:9100,http://server4.domain.com:9100,http://server5.domain:9100,http://server6.domain:9100" \
```